# PHP: preg_match_all causing 403 when matching newlines

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp, preg-match-all, http-status-code-403

I just ran into strange problem. I'm using XAMPP and codeigniter framework at the moment.

I need to match shortcodes, my regex was:

```
\[(background)=?(.*?)\](.+?)\[/\1\]
```

But it didnt match content if there was new lines between tags, so I changed it to:

```
\[(background)=?(.*?)\]((.|\n)*)\[/\1\]
```

After change, site gives me 403 error. If I change it back, it works.

Whole code:

```
while (preg_match_all('`\[(background)=?(.*?)\]((.|\n)*)\[/\1\]`', $string, $matches)) foreach ($matches[0] as $key => $match) {
    list($tag, $param, $innertext) = array($matches[1][$key], $matches[2][$key], $matches[3][$key]);
    switch ($tag) {
        ...
    }
    $string = str_replace($match, $replacement, $string);
}
```

This is what error log gives me:

```
[Tue Jan 06 03:12:56.101114 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 10580:tid 596] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for www.example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Jan 06 03:12:56.145116 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10580:tid 596] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Anybody had similar problems and managed to fix it?

Comment: The error is not related to preg_match_all().

Comment: Well, it works before I change my regex. I have tested few others which should match newlines but result is always same so far.

Comment: Where is $string coming from?  I presume https://www.example.com.
The problem is with your security certificate.  If you can use http rather than https the problem will go away.
Or on the examle.com server generate a certificate and install it on your local machine running the PHP.

Comment: I have no idea why is apache error log giving me example.com SSL error. Example.com is not related with my site any way.

Code is used inside function which should replace shortcodes (as used in wordpress). $string is just passed to function and its content from database.

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted to hide the identity of the actual site and edited the error to reflect example.com rather than the actual site.
Somewhere in your code or includes is a link to https://www.example.com. Use a text search tool (e.g. Notepad++ find in files search feature) to find "example.com" in all the files related to your app.